# UnrealIRCd update list of allowed channels dynamically

Tags: linux, server, irc

I am running UnrealIRCd on a linux machine.

I want only a specific number of channels to be available to the users which they can join.

I have the following configuration

```
deny channel {
        channel "*";
        reason "This is not an allowed channel";
};

allow channel {
        channel "#testroom*";
};
```

I would like to allow more channels that maynot be captured by "#testroom*" dynamically.

One way was to edit the config file and restart the server. However doing that disconnects all users.

How can i add new allowed channels without causing the disconnect?

Comment: also i would like to know what upgrade-conf exactly does. 
I tried doing unrealircd upgrade-conf, but it says the conf files have not changed even though they have

Answer (score 0):

An oper with the `can_rehash` privilege can use the `/REHASH` command to cause the server to reload its config file without restarting.  Alternatively, you can send a `SIGHUP` signal the process to cause the same effect.